# Rails Setup act as commentable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

after setting the gem everything is working greatly but after post the user comment  did save in db someone know why?

the db

> Comment id: 12, title: "", comment: nil, commentable_id: 36,
>   commentable_type: "Dispute", user_id: 12, created_at: "2017-05-21
>   05:27:42", updated_at: "2017-05-21 05:27:42"

```
dispute controller


 def show
    @dispute = @order.dispute
    @comments = @dispute.comments.all

@comment = @dispute.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
  end

dispite show view

<%= form_for [ @dispute, @comment], :url =>  order_dispute_comments_path  do |f|-%>
  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", :class => "btn_green" %>
<% end -%>




routes

   resources :orders  do 
     resource :dispute do
     resources :comments
   end
end

comments controller

def create
 # @dispute = @dispute.find params[:dispute_id]
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @dispute = @order.dispute
  @comment = @dispute.comments.new params[:comment]
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
   redirect_to order_dispute_path
  end
end
end
```

Comment: "after post the user comment did save in db "

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Hello @Bartosz, save but did not comment. as you can see the comment stays nil